# pandas - join words after specific word

Tags: python, pandas, text-mining

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of comments in the form

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'comment':['aaa bbb ccc not verb ddd']}) 
df.loc[0,'comment']

'aaa bbb ccc not verb ddd'
```

I want to join together the `not` with the word after it, in the example `verb` as `not_verb`, and return the rest of the row as is:

```
'aaa bbb ccc not_verb ddd'
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**

Basically I'd like to join from " not " to the end of the word following it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.replace`:

```
df.comment.str.replace(r'\b(not\s)', 'not_')
```

Output:

```
0    aaa bbb ccc not_verb ddd
Name: comment, dtype: object
```